# Wrapping text in column

Tags: flutter

I'm building an expenses app, and have: 
[image]

As you can see, I have a text overflow problem. I want that text to trim with ellipses, but I'm not sure how to do it. Currently I have:

```
  Widget buildCardLeft() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Text(
            this.transaction.title,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ),
        Text(
          dateFormat.format(this.transaction.date),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        )
      ],
    );
```

What's the correct way to get this text to truncate?

Answer (score 2):

you can say like:

```
Text(
this.transaction.title.replaceRange(25, this.transaction.title.length, "...",
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `Flexible`:

```
  Widget buildCardLeft() {
    return Container(
      child: Flexible(
        flex: 1,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              this.transaction.title,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              dateFormat.format(this.transaction.date),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```